# How do I send a SIGINT signal to a running process in an iTerm2 session using python?

Tags: python, iterm2

I'm trying to automate the restarting of several servers running in iTerm2 tabs using iTerm2's [Python API](https://iterm2.com/python-api/index.html). I can get a reference to the sessions, and issue commands to them (with `async_send_text`), but I can't figure out how to send SIGINT signals to them so I can issue the restart commands.

I've seen a few answers using AppleScript, but it seems like this should be possible in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.kill()` to send signals to a process as long as you have the process ID:

```
import os
import signal

os.kill(<PID>, signal.SIGINT)
```

This should work even when the process is in running in a terminal emulator.

Comment: pid may be available but I haven’t figured out where to access it. I ended up sending the following text to the session: \x03

Comment: @user6689821 You can run `ps aux` to get the process ID.